# Memory issue using ARC in big for loop using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, memory, nsarray, nsjsonserialization

I'am currently trying to create a function that make a lot json serialization from NSString.

```
NSArray* array = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
for (NSObject* obj in otherArray) { 
    array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[obj.json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    // I'm using array here .. and then i don't need it anymore
}
```

Here my otherArray could be quite large and obj.json too.

But after a while the application is crashing because of memory issue (> 1GB).
It seems that my array is never dealloc in the for loop because when I comment the line I don't get any error ..
How can I do to free the memory using ARC ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an autorelease pool block inside the loop to reduce the program’s memory footprint:

```
NSArray* array = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
for (NSObject* obj in otherArray) { 
    @autoreleasepool {
        array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[obj.json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        // I'm using array here .. and then i don't need it anymore
    }
}
```

> Many programs create temporary objects that are autoreleased. These
>   objects add to the program’s memory footprint until the end of the
>   block. In many situations, allowing temporary objects to accumulate
>   until the end of the current event-loop iteration does not result in
>   excessive overhead; in some situations, however, you may create a
>   large number of temporary objects that add substantially to memory
>   footprint and that you want to dispose of more quickly. In these
>   latter cases, you can create your own autorelease pool block. At the
>   end of the block, the temporary objects are released, which typically
>   results in their deallocation thereby reducing the program’s memory
>   footprint.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-SW2

Comment: I was just reading the apple doc about @autorealeasepool block and I think this is the perfect solution for my issue ! Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. Please do not forget to accept my answer, thank you :)